# How many total permutations with multiple restrictions?

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I have a list of colors:

black white red blue yellow green orange purple

And the following colors cannot be arranged together:

black white

blue green

orange black

red blue

green yellow

white purple

How many total ways are there to arrange these colors?

I know how to solve it if there was only one condition.

It would be 8! - (2! * 7!).

Since there are 6 conditions, how would I solve this?

Comment: Probably [inclusion-exclusion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle)

Comment: On reflection, I reluctantly agree with the comment of @angryavian.  Normally, one might wonder if the alternative (direct) approach might yield a more elegant solution.  If you number the colors black=1, ..., purple=8, then the **outlawed chains** can be represented as 7-1-2-8 and 3-4-6-5.  However, personally, I see no way of using this *vision* to facilitate a direct approach.  Cumbersome as it is, for someone experienced in Inclusion-Exclusion, the computations would take less than an hour.  It is expected that it will take you longer, assuming that you are inexperienced in inclusion-excl.

Comment: For any set $A$ with a finite number of elements, let $|A|$ denote the number of elements in $A$.  Per previous comment, let $S$ denote the set of all permutations.  Let $S_1$ denote the subset of $S$ where the constraint against 7-1 is violated.  Define $S_2, S_3, \cdots, S_6$ similarly.  Then, you want $|S| - |S_1 \cup \cdots \cup S_6|.$

Comment: Re previous comment, Let $T_0 = |S|.$  For $r \in \{1,2,3,4,5,6\},$ let $$T_r = \sum_{1 \leq i_1 < i_2 < \cdots < i_r \leq 6} |S_{i_1} \cap S_{i_2} \cap \cdots ... \cap S_{i_r}|.$$  That is, $T_r$ represents the sum of $~\displaystyle \binom{6}{r}$ terms.  Then, per Inclusion-Exclusion, the desired computation is $$\sum_{r=0}^6 (-1)^r T_r.$$